# Inner Join on many-to-many relationship on the same table

Tags: mysql

I came across a weird problem while I was trying to apply the `Inner Join` on the table which has 3 columns -

Table `category_subcategory_relation`

```
id (PK)
category_id_ref (FK)
subcategory_id_ref (FK)
```

The columns `category_id_ref` and `subcategory_id_ref` are the `primary keys` of the table `category`.

Table `category`

```
id (PK)
category_name (Varchar(200))
```

I want to Inner Join this two tables and get the columns as following -

```
Category_Name
Subcategory_Name
```

I am not able understand how would I be able to get the `category_name` column from the `category` table twice, once for the column `Category_Name (FK)` and again for the column `Child_Category_Name (FK)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to perform two joins, one each on `category_id_ref` and `subcategory_id_ref`:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.category_name AS Category_Name, 
       c.category_name AS Subcategory_Name
FROM category_subcategory_relation a 
JOIN category b 
  ON a.category_id_ref    = b.id
JOIN category c 
  ON a.subcategory_id_ref = c.id
```

While your `category` table contains category and subcategory information, you'll have to look at them as two separate tables (one for `category` and other for `subcategory`) to bring this information back to your `category_subcategory_relation` table.